# Linq to entities - Lambda - Concatenate strings

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I would like to concatenate a string using lambda to compare that concatenated value against a certain condition.

```
Invoices = Invoices.Where(f => ((string)f.invoice_prefix + String.Format("{0:0000}", Convert.ToInt32(f.invoice_number))).ToLower().Equals(condition7));
```

But I get an error message :

> The name 'f' does not exist in the current context

Tried several String.Format and String.Concat variants like

```
Invoices = Invoices.Where(f => (String.Format("{0}{1}",f.invoice_prefix,String.Format("{0:0000}", Convert.ToInt32(f.invoice_number)))).ToLower().Equals(condition7));
```

but no success... Can somebody help me with the syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to Entities doesn't understand all of the .NET framework methods.

In order to run this as a SQL statement on the database, you need to only use operators that can be converted to SQL. That means you need to re-write your predicate using primitive data types.

So something like this:

```
string prefixCondition = ...
int invoiceNumberCondition = ...

Invoices.Where( f =>
  f.invoice_prefix == prefixCondition
  &&
  f.invoice_number == invoiceNumberCondition 
)
```

I recommend using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test with, as it shows you the generated SQL statement.

Comment: Question is tagged to be about Entity Framework rather than linq to sql, but the same considerations will apply.

Comment: @AakashM I wrote Linq to Entities. Someone edited it to Linq to SQL - I don't know why. I've reverted the edit.

Comment: Little Substring struggle with the prefixcondition because the prefix can vary, but it worked. tnx!